# change select element color to another when open

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

New to Material ui, i have this select element, i want to change the color of that input in the image to same as that 'None' section when select is clicked, so when user is able to see 'None' section then that input above it should have same background color as 'None' section and then when drop down is closed that input should change to gray

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6hs9mm?file=/demo.js

code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    display: 'block',
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  select: {
    borderBottom: 'opx',
    '& ul': {
      paddingTop: '0px',
      paddingBottom: '0px',
    },
    '& ul:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#1E2328',
    },
   
    '& .Mui-selected': {
      backgroundColor: '#1E2328',
      color: '#E9ECEC',
      fontWeight: '400, regular',
    },
    '& .Mui-selected:hover': {
      backgroundColor: '#1E2328',
    },
  },
  menuItemm: {
    display: 'flex',
    width: '225px',
    height: '56px',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    // border: '1px solid gray',
    backgroundColor: '#0B0B0B',
    color: 'white',
  },
  placeholder: {
    color: '#E9ECEC',
  },
}));

export default function ControlledOpenSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
 
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel  style={{backgroundColor:"gray",color:"white"}} id="demo-controlled-open-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          style={{backgroundColor:"gray",color:"white"}}
          open={open}
          MenuProps={{
            classes: { paper: classes.select },
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: 'bottom',
              horizontal: 'left',
            },
            transformOrigin: {
              vertical: 'top',
              horizontal: 'left',
            },
            getContentAnchorEl: null,
          }}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={age}
         
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem                           className={classes.menuItemm}
 value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem                           className={classes.menuItemm}
 value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem                           className={classes.menuItemm}
 value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

these two should have same color when drop down is open:

[image]

and then when drop down is closed that input should change to gray color (backgroundColor).

i tried using usestate but then it changes color after dropdown is closed and not when opened:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2k0sow?file=/demo.js

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes

Comment: any advice is appreciated !

Comment: any advice is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

You should change this part

```
<Select labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: open ? "#1E2328" : "gray",
            color: "white"
          }}
```

Here is the `codesandbox` link https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-exjez3?file=/demo.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    display: "block",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  select: {
    borderBottom: "opx",
    "& ul": {
      paddingTop: "0px",
      paddingBottom: "0px"
    },
    "& ul:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#1E2328"
    },

    "& .Mui-selected": {
      backgroundColor: "#1E2328",
      color: "#E9ECEC",
      fontWeight: "400, regular"
    },
    "& .Mui-selected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "#1E2328"
    }
  },
  menuItemm: {
    display: "flex",
    width: "225px",
    height: "56px",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    // border: '1px solid gray',
    backgroundColor: "#0B0B0B",
    color: "white"
  },
  placeholder: {
    color: "#E9ECEC"
  }
}));

export default function ControlledOpenSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel
          style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", color: "white" }}
          id="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
        >
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
          id="demo-controlled-open-select"
          style={{
            backgroundColor: open ? "#1E2328" : "gray",
            color: "white"
          }}
          open={open}
          MenuProps={{
            classes: { paper: classes.select },
            anchorOrigin: {
              vertical: "bottom",
              horizontal: "left"
            },
            transformOrigin: {
              vertical: "top",
              horizontal: "left"
            },
            getContentAnchorEl: null
          }}
          onClose={handleClose}
          onOpen={handleOpen}
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem className={classes.menuItemm} value={10}>
            Ten
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem className={classes.menuItemm} value={20}>
            Twenty
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem className={classes.menuItemm} value={30}>
            Thirty
          </MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: hey i forgot to change the code, there is not setOpen and open, i tried implement your answer here but does not work: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nxft5r?file=/demo.js